# How to define a coin-flipping probability measure on $\{0,1\}^E$, where $E$ is a continuum subset of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $E=[0,1]$, and every $0\le x \le 1$ represents a coin flipper that flips an identical coin. Then $\{0,1\}^E$ is the collection of all results. Given that the probability of "Head" is $p$, how can I define a probability measure on $\{0,1\}^E$?

I have been searching for the answer and found this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85837/can-we-put-a-probability-measure-on-every-sigma-algebra?newreg=b6d27e95b02744fd935573764be651a3. However, the OP didn't mention how a "coin-flipping measure with infinite exponent" can be written out. I've searched around and can't seem to figure out.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The basic answer is that the "product measure" construction works for uncountable products just as well as countable.  However, you get a measure defined on the product $\sigma$-field which is awkwardly small - smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the product topology, in particular - and many interesting "events" turn out to be non-measurable.  So this construction usually turns out not to be very useful in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will note the rules more carefully.

While I understand the concept, it's still puzzling to me how the pdf of the product distribution looks like. I'm doing this for a practical problem and have to be able to numerically integrate.

I'm not a Math major, and don't understand many things completely. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: A pdf is by definition a density with respect to Lebesgue measure - it only makes sense for (some) measures on Euclidean space.  $\{0,1\}^E$ doesn't have a Lebesgue measure so this measure doesn't have a pdf - the notion doesn't make sense here.  In a numerical example, I doubt you really need uncountably many coins - if you inspect the problem carefully I bet you will find you only need countably, or finitely, many.

Comment: Can you say more about the "practical problem" you are really trying to solve?   I suspect that uncountable coin-flipping measure will turn out not to be the right tool.

Comment: Start by looking at random sets.  http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Random_sets. The function you are looking at is the indicator function for a random set.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. They are certainly very helpful. I have found a workaround of this problem and will use a method less technical.